# Jetty nonblocking by default?

Tags: jetty, nonblocking

Please tell me, 
Is Jetty non-blocking web server by default or not?

For example, this code below runs Jetty as non-blocking web server?

```
Server server = new Server(8080);

ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

context.setContextPath("/");

server.setHandler(context);

context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new MyServlet()),"/*");

server.start();

server.join();
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on which version of Jetty you're using.

- In Jetty 6, the "Server(int port)" constructor would open a blocking connector on that port.
- In Jetty 7, the "Server(int port)" constructor opens a non-blocking connector on that port.

If you really care about the behaviour, you're better off configuring the connector yourself, rather than relying on that convenience constructor.