# Blocking vs Non blocking main thread in tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

Normally in tomcat, a *thread* will be running and when a request comes in,it will assign the responsibility of servicing the request to a thread from thread pool.

Does it matter if that main *thread* is blocking or non blocking in terms of scalability?

Comment: blocking io / non blocking io

Comment: The term main thread has an actual significance in Java. The thread that starts the application (tomcat) is executed on the main thread.  Do you mean the thread executing the request?

Comment: @JohnVint I mean the *thread* that receives the requests and invokes a thread from thread pool to handle each request.

Comment: Does it matter in terms of what? performance? scalability? API for the servlet developer? memory usage?

Comment: @JBNizet in terms of scalability

Answer (score 2):

Non Blocking IO has the following advantages:

- **Highly Scalable :** Because no-more you require one thread per client. It can effectively support more number of clients.
- **High Keep Alive :** Blocking IO requires to block until the keepalive time for the next request. Non-Blocking being notification model, it can support high keepalive times.
- **Better Performance on High Load :** Because in blocking IO has one thread per connection, it requires n threads for n connections. As the value n increases, the performance degrades because more thread context switching.

Comment: One thing about non-blocking io in java: It is kinda hard to do. Let's say you are using a db framework like jdo. Every operation on the database is blocking. I would probably go for nodejs if I wanted to write a non-blocking http server.

Answer (score 1):

When an incoming request is processed in tomcat it will assign the connection to a thread from its thread pool.

What matters here is to run the thread as fast as possible. You typically run blocking io calls in this thread, for file io, db and so on.

You need to adjust the size of this thread pool apropriatley to handle your expected traffic.

Esentially when using the Java EE servlet spec you are forced into handling your requests in a one thread per incoming connection manner.

There are a few non blocking frameworks out there. Check out http://www.playframework.org/ and Jetty ( [Jetty nonblocking by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156420/jetty-nonblocking-by-default) )